# Joomla 2.5 CSRF Attack

Tags: php, joomla

My website is under security audit.

CSRF attack is pop up in Joomla administrator part. I have read the topic written on [Joomla website](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_add_CSRF_anti-spoofing_to_forms)

but not able to understand it.

Can anyone tell me where I have to add tokens.

Like if we take specific example of com_content in this location:

```
\www\joomla\administrator\components\com_content\views\articles\tmpl\default.php
```

This page is Article page where we see list of all the articles. Inside the view form, I have added this script:

```
<?php echo JHtml::_( 'form.token' ); ?>
```

From this page, we can either edit the page or create new page.

Now Where I have to add a script to check while token sent from previous page is valid or not. How can I validate it?

Comment: @Kumar KL Their are some important comments where they have been I haven't ask you to edit my question.

Comment: Joomla already manages the tokens for the core components. What exactly is the problem you are tryng to solve. What do you mean by "CSRF pops up'?  Automated security checks are often really inaccurate for dynamic software like Joomla because they don't understand the deep security features, which are different than what you need when you have a static html site.